# F# SQLProvider - NULL in where clause

Tags: database, f#, type-providers

I have a query where I want to get all records having `NULL` in certain column:

```
query {
    for a in db.Dbo.DataAlert do
    where (a.DateSent = null)
    select a
}
```

However, this throws an error saying that null is not a valid value.

What is the correct way to write that query?

**UPDATE:** I'm using [this SQLProvider](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider).

Comment: It would seem that SQLProvider doesn't generate nullable properties for nullable column tables. You should probably use LINQ with EF or another ORM instead. Side-note: I can't believe how ... involved ... it is to use F# for ETL. Try sending a type provider column to SqlBulkCopy for example

Comment: Which SQLProvider are you using btw, and doesn't `isNull` do what you want?

Comment: @s952163 I've added the link.

Comment: @s952163 that provider is actually called [SQLProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLProvider) and doesn't generate nullable columns. FSharp.Data.SqlClient doesn't work with LINQ.  If you have any other type provider in mind I'd be as interested as the OP to know

Comment: Yes, you're right, I recall refactoring a bunch of Nullable data items when moved to postgres+sqlprovider. However you can use Option types with it and then check for Some/None. You could also reverse the query and check if it's not int, or whatever value a.DataSent can take.

Comment: @Anil I just rememberd you can use the `UseOptionTypes` parameter to get option types for nullable fields.

Comment: @s952163 the issue here is that the default behaviour is the opposite of the expected one. By default Option types are off.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate Option types for nullable columns by specifying the [UseOptionTypes](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/parameters.html#UseOptionTypes) static parameter. The default value is `false` which returns eg 0 instead of NULL. This isn't very well documented in the docs, eg no mention in the [Querying](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/querying.html) documentation page, and only a single example in the [Home](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/index.html) page.

Once you set UseOptionTypes to `true` :

```
type sql = SqlDataProvider< 
              ConnectionString = connectionString,
              DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER,
              UseOptionTypes = true
              >
```

The nullable fields will return Option types, allowing you to write:

```
query {
    for a in db.Dbo.DataAlert do
    where (a.DateSent = None)
    select a
}
```

Comment: Yes, indeed! I think he wants `a.DateSent = None`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way would be to specify `useOptTypes = true` as in the other answer. However that might involve refactoring other code on your end. If you cannot do that for whatever reason that you will need to check for the defaultValue of null. So for example if that column's type is `string`, then "", or if it's and `int` then 0.